# Error deploying context tomcat

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2, openbravo

I am trying to run an open source ERP software called Openbravo, I am using amazon EC2 web services. I am successfully logged into the system through VMWare terminal using ssh. That part goes all fine. But when I execute the following commands to stop and restart the tomcat service, I get an error at Deploying context [fail].
Please let me know what kind of log files you need. I have  the contents of catalina.log

I have increased the memory by changing tomcat.sh Xmx1024M to Xmx2048M but still the same error.

```
# /tmp/hs_err_pid6079.log
CompilerOracle: excludenet/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRGridLayout.horizontallyMergeEmptyCells
Aug 14, 2015 2:49:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init 
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-127.0.0.1-8009"]
Aug 14, 2015 2:49:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1007 ms
Aug 14, 2015 2:49:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 14, 2015 2:49:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
Aug 14, 2015 2:49:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/openbravo
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000007b5f4b000, 196608, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate mem$
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 196608 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/hs_err_pid6733.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that the partition on which the JVM's working directory sits isn't out of space (or that you are being constrained by a quota or similar). We had this error some up a few times when disk space got tight due to a runaway log file: plenty of free memory on the server... very low disk space.

Comment: There is 131GB free space on the partition. I guess this should be enough right?

Comment: I suppose you could have a really huge heap that wouldn't fit on that ;) What about a quota or anything like that?

Comment: Hi Christopher, I am not sure what you mean by a quota, could you provide more information?

Comment: Some environments have disk-quotas enforced, so you can only use-up, say, 1GiB of disk space even though the partition has some huge amount of space available in total. That's probably not the issue. What about swap space?

Comment: Running under the same environment/account as the JVM process, what are the `ulimits` of that user? Perhaps you have a per-process memory limit you are reaching? Raising `-Xmx` is likely making the problem worse.